# How to tell if Postgres was built with the option to include LLVM technology for JIT?

Tags: postgresql, jit

[Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) 11 gained the [ability](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit.html) to perform [Just-in-Time Compilation (JIT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) based on [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) technology.

The [manual notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit-reason.html) that this feature depends on Postgres having been built with the [`--with-llvm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-procedure.html#CONFIGURE-WITH-LLVM) option.

➥ How can one verify their build of Postgres includes LLVM?

Assuming LLVM is installed… In Postgres 11, JIT is disabled by default. In Postgres 12, the feature is enabled. That raises the question:

➥ How can one tell if JIT is currently enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Is LLVM built-in?

You can run [`pg_config --configure`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgconfig.html) to see with which flags and options your version was compiled.

To quote the documentation:

> Print the options that were given to the configure script when PostgreSQL was configured for building. This can be used to reproduce the identical configuration, or to find out with what options a binary package was built.

## Is JIT enabled?

To check if JIT is enabled, examine the configuration variable named [`jit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-JIT).

```
show jit ;
```

## Is JIT available?

Call the [system information function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-info.html) `pg_jit_available` to see if JIT can be used in this session. Returns `false` if [`jit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-JIT) is set to `false`.

```
SELECT pg_jit_available() ;
```